# Quickest Queue Container (C++)

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using queue's and priority queues, through which I plan on pumping a lot of data quite quickly.

Therefore, I want my q's and pq's to be responsive to additions and subtractions.

What are the relative merits of using a vector, list, or deque as the underlying container?

**Update:**
At the time of writing, both Mike Seymour and Steve Townsend's answers below are worth reading. Thanks both!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to be sure how the choice effects performance is to measure it, in a situation similar to your expected use cases. That said, here are some observations:

For `std::queue`:

- `std::deque` is usually the best choice; it supports all the necessary operations in constant time, and allocates memory in chunks as it grows.
- `std::list` also supports the necessary operations, but may be slower due to more memory allocations; in special circumstances, you might be able to get good results by allocating from a dedicated object pool, but that's not entirely straightforward.
- `std::vector` can't be used as it doesn't have a `pop_front()` operation; such an operation would be slow, as it would have to move all the remaining elements.

A potentially faster, but less flexible, alternative is to implement a circular buffer over a fixed-size array (e.g. `std::array`, or a `std::vector` that you don't resize). You'll need to deal with the case of it filling up, either by reporting an error, or allocating a larger buffer and copying all the data.

For `std::priority_queue`:

- `std::vector` is usually the best choice; it grows exponentially (reducing the number of memory allocations), and is a simple data structure that's very fast to access - an iterator can be implemented simply as a wrapper around a pointer.
- `std::deque` may be slower as it typically grows linearly (requiring more memory allocation), and access is more complicated than with a vector.
- `std::list` can't be used as it doesn't provide random access.

To summarise - the defaults are usually the best choice, but if speed really is important, then measure the alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `std::queue` for your basic queue which is (by default at least) a wrapper on `deque`.  Do something more special-purpose if that does not work for you.

`std::priority_queue` also exists (over `vector` by default) but the added semantics make it more likely that you could have to roll your own here, depending on perf observed for your particular access pattern.

`vector` has storage characteristics which make it very ill-suited to removal from front of the dataset.  A lot of shuffling down to be done every time you `pop_front`.  For a simple queue, avoid this.

`list` is likely to be too expensive for any high-hit queue, because by contract it has to offer function you don't need.  It could be a candidate for use as a priority queue but my instinct is always to trust the STL.

Comment: I don't understand your first line, Steve. I must, in my design, use both queues and priority queues. The question is what underlying container should I use for them? Queue uses `deque` by default. I'm not sure that priority queue has a default, but I'm presently using `vector`.

Comment: @Richard: `vector` can't be used for `queue`, since it doesn't provide `pop_front()`. It's a good choice (and the default) for `priority_queue`, which only pushes and pops from the back of the container.

Comment: @Richard - like the STL usage suggests, I doubt you can use the same underlying storage for your queue and your priority_queue with optimal results for both.  Does that clarify?

Comment: I quite agree, @SteveTownsend. It was probably poor style to address both data structures in the same question.

Comment: You were right, @SteveTownsend. The vector-based priority queue seems to be unnaturally slow when adding elements whose priority is larger than any already present in the queue. Identifying such elements and pushing them through a FIFO queue led to a 37% increase in speed in one algorithm.

Comment: @Richard - nice. Measuring under a real world usage pattern is the best way to decide what to 'fix'.

Answer (score 3):

`vector` would implement a stack as your fast insertion is at the end and fast removal is also at the end. If you want a FIFO queue, `vector` would be the wrong implementation to use.

`deque` or `list` both provide constant time insertion at either end. `list` is good for LRU caches where you want to move elements out of the middle fast and where you want your iterators to remain valid no matter how much you move them about. `deque` is generally used when insertions and deletions are at the end.

The main thing I need to ask about your collection is whether they are accessed by multiple threads. I sort-of assume they are, in which case one of your primary aims is to reduce locking. This is best done if you at least have a multi_push and multi_get feature so that you can put more than one element on at a time without any locking.

There are also lock-free containers or semi-lock-free containers.

You will probably find that your locking strategy is more important than any performance in the collection itself as long as your operations are all constant-time.